# Can the statal passive be used in the form "ist… zur Verfügung gesteht"?

Tags: verb-usage, passive, collocation

I wish to add a sentence to [a software manual](https://github.com/TVTower/TVTower/blob/master/docs/manual_de.md) in German, with a meaning like this:

> This keyboard shortcut is not available in the developer version.

I think that this translation is the simplest choice:

> Dieses Tastenkürzel ist in der Entwicklerversion nicht verfügbar.

as I found it used in a very similar context in another software manual:

[image: Google Books snippet of "nicht verfügbar" form]

However, I noticed that the original writer of our manual preferred **zur Verfügung stehen** in these contexts. This is in line with the suggestion in [an earlier question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32126/what-exactly-does-zur-verf%C3%BCgung-stellen-mean-in-this-context) that the very similar **zur Verfügung stellen** collocation is often used in software development, though our manual never uses **stellen**, only **stehen**.

The problem is which verb form to use. The regular passive is:

> Dieses Tastenkürzel wird in der Entwicklerversion nicht zur Verfügung <s>gesteht</s> gestanden.

But the answers and comments to the earlier question said that regular passive with **stellen** would be the equivalent of a future or progressive tense in English. I want to describe the present state of the software, so the "regular" passive does not seem suitable.

The statal passive is:

> Dieses Tastenkürzel ist in der Entwicklerversion nicht zur Verfügung <s>gesteht</s> gestanden.

This emphasizes that the present state is the result of a previous action. That is the truth; the shortcut has been deliberately removed in the developer version. But the original author never used **zur Verfügung stehen** in the statal passive, Google Books does not have any recent examples of **zur Verfügung gestanden** (or **...gesteht**, my mistaken conjugation) in the statal passive, and [a random person](https://hinative.com/ko/questions/1207861?utm_content=adjacent_next&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=hinative) on the Internet says it is wrong.

So can you use the statal passive form, **ist + zur Verfügung <s>gesteht</s> gestanden** or is that collocation wrong?

I know that German uses passive voice much less than English does. Is there some non-passive form of **zur Verfügung stehen** that I should use instead?

Comment: In addition to the answer: the participle is "gestanden", not "gesteht" (which happens to be third person singular present tense of "gestehen").

Comment: @CarstenS: Thank you Carsten. I have made an elementary mistake there and will update the question accordingly.

Comment: @CarstenS I woould have rather said it is "zur Verfügung gestellt" for the first sample sentence - from "stellen". Oops, that  was already said further down the thread:-)

Comment: Actually a passive of stehen is possible, but because stehen is intransitive it's the impersonal passive: *Es wird gestanden*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Summary

*Zur Verfügung stehen* already refers to a **state** in **active**, so the sentence of choice to describe the state is:

> Dieses Tastenkürzel **steht** in der Entwicklerversion nicht zur Verfügung.

*Zur Verfügung <s>gesteht</s>* is ungrammatical (i.e., "wrong"). The past participle of *stehen* would be *gestanden*, but isn't applicable here anyway.

---

I will address some aspects of this individually:

#### There is no passive of *stehen*.

There is no regular passive voice of *stehen* ('to stand'), because it is an intransitive verb. To my knowledge, there is no regular passive of the English equivalent *to stand* in the meaning 'to be upright' either.

#### *Stehen* is the result of *stellen*

*Stehen* means 'to stand', *stellen* means 'to make sth. stand'. Hence, *stehen* is kind of an *Zustands**aktiv*** for the result of *stellen*. If you want for some reason to construct the *Zustands**passiv*** (present tense) for something that literally 'is made stand', you would have to use *stellen*:

> *uncommon:*
>  ?Dieses Tastenkürzel **ist** in der Entwicklerversion nicht zur Verfügung **gestellt**.

This sentence is very uncommon und arguably considered bad style because it is unnecessarily complicated. It basically emanates from *stehen*, takes a detour to *stellen* to construct the *Zustandspassiv*, just to end up with the same meaning as *stehen* again.

Since you are looking for an impersonal wording, you are perfectly right that you haven't considered the *Vorgangspassiv* (which has an implied subject).  If personalness is desired, however, *Vorgangspassiv* would be stylistically be more acceptable than *Zustandspassiv* as @O.R.Mapper and @DonHogo pointed out:

> *not impersonal:*
> Dieses Tastenkürzel **wird** in der Entwicklerversion nicht zur Verfügung **gestellt.**
> ≈ **Man stellt** das Tastenkürzel in der Entwicklerversion nicht zur Verfügung.

So:

#### *zur Verfügung gestellt sein* = *zur Verfügung stehen*

Since *stehen* ('to stand') equals *gestellt sein* ('to be made stand'), *zur Verfügung stehen* means nothing other than *zur Verfügung gestellt sein*.

Thus, the clear recommendation is:

> Dieses Tastenkürzel steht in der Entwicklerversion nicht zur Verfügung.

Comment: This answer is extremely well-written and I will accept it immediately because I doubt that anyone can improve on it. The key point I missed is that **stehen** is intransitive, but you have also kindly explained the correct relationship between **stehen** and **stellen**. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Matthew: I would indeed like to add a remark, which may be tangential on the grammar side of things, but relevant for choice of words: "... steht nicht zur Verfügung" just describes a fact, without giving any hint about the reasons. "... wird nicht zur Verfügung gestellt", in contrast, sounds much more "active" and implies that someone (you/the software author!) had consciously decided against making the function available (in the worst case, even intentionally making it unusable). Usually, this is not the idea you want to convey to users.

Comment: You could add that Vorgangspassiv (_wird zur Verfügung gestellt_) would work much better than Zustandspassiv in this case and isn't even totally uncommon. Still worse than simply _stehen_, though.

Comment: Matthew: My pleasure! @O.R.Mapper and DonHolgo: Thanks for the remarks, added a paragraph.